# undefined reference статической переменной класса

Tags: c++, qt

Имею класс:

```
#include <QObject>    
class MyClass: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static void myFunc();
    static int myCount;
};

#include "myclass.h"    
void MyClass::myFunc()
{
    myCount = 10;
}
```

При компиляции ошибка: `undefined reference to 'MyClass::myCount'`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C++ статические переменные класса необходимо явно определять. В .cpp файле напишите:

```
int MyClass::myCount = 0;
```

В глобальной области видимости.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу ixSci:

Начиная с С++17 альтернативным вариантом решения является определение статического члена как inline

```
class MyClass
{
  ...
  inline static int myCount;
  ...
};
```

В таком варианте дополнительное определение за пределами класса не нужно.